# WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped

Tags: cdi

I recently upgraded Netbeans and java to the latest versions and have been getting the following error. When I run my application it works fine. But when I refresh the Prmefaces screen that calls the class shown below I get the following error. I have reviewed several similar questions here but none seems to clarify my problem.

FATAL:   JSF1073: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException caught during processing of RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
FATAL:   WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MainController implements Serializable 
{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<String> selectedBrands;
private List<SelectItem> brandCategories;

public MainController() 
{ 
    selectedBrands = new ArrayList<>();
    brandCategories = new ArrayList<>();
}

public List<SelectItem> getBrandCategories() 
{

    brandCategories.clear();

    SelectItemGroup brand = new SelectItemGroup("");

    brand.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[]
    {
        new SelectItem(Messages.ELECTROLUX, Messages.ELECTROLUX),
        new SelectItem(Messages.LG, Messages.LG),
        new SelectItem(Messages.WHIRLPOOL, Messages.WHIRLPOOL),
        new SelectItem(Messages.FRIGIDAIRE, Messages.FRIGIDAIRE)            
    });

    brandCategories.add(brand);

    return brandCategories;
}
```

}